# Make sense of for-loops

Tags: python, for-loop

I don't understand something in for-loops, when i write

```
names = ["Mark", "Cyr", "Hunt", "Dave", "Crock"] 

for name in names:
    print "Here is the list of criminals %r" %names
```

The output would be this.

```
Here is the list of criminals: Mark, Cyr, Hunt, Dave, Crock
Here is the list of criminals: Mark, Cyr, 'Hunt, Dave, Crock
Here is the list of criminals: Mark, Cyr, Hunt, Dave, Crock
Here is the list of criminals: Mark, Cyr, Hunt, Dave, Crock
Here is the list of criminals: Mark, Cyr, Hunt, Dave, Crock
```

But if i make a slight change to it, like this.

```
for i in names:
    print "Here is the list of criminals: %r" %i
```

The output would be like this

```
Here is the list of criminals: Mark
Here is the list of criminals: Cyr
Here is the list of criminals: Hunt
Here is the list of criminals: Dave
Here is the list of criminals: Crock
```

But why is that. Why when i put %i instead of names the out-put Change completely

Comment: put the statement before the for loop makes more sense

Answer (score 3):

In your first loop you are printing `names`, which is the *whole list*.  So, for each element in the list, you're printing the whole list.

Perhaps you meant to print `name`?

Answer (score 0):

First, what you did was two things:

- You replaced the loop variable `name` with `i`.
- And you replaced the second operand to the formatting operator `%`. It was `names` and is now `i`.

This means two things:

- It is now `i` instead of `name` that takes the value of each of the elements of `names` on each iteration when executing the `for` loop.
- For each iteration, that value in `i` (i.e., an element of the list `names`) gets formatted by the `%` operator into the format defined by `"Here is the list of criminals: %r"`, so the resulting, printed string will be `"Here is the list of criminals: "` appended with the value of `i` instead of that string appended with the entire value of the list in `names`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have 5 elements in your list, so the for loop will loop 5 times.

Your original code effectively says this:
Execute the print statement 5 times.  Each time put the whole list called `names` where `%r` is.

Your second version says this:
Execute the print statement 5 times. Each time put the current name (represented by the variable named `i`) where `%r` is.

My guess is that the trailing 's' on `names` was the typo in the 1st version as John mentioned.